# Swift: score increases by 2 and not 1 when contact is detected?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Alright, so I'm keeping score in a sprite kit game and the score is stored in a variable named `animalsCount`. Here I set up the variable and the label node it is outputting to:

```
    //Score count in stats bar
    //Animal score count

    animalsCount = 0

    animalsCountLabel.text = "\(animalsCount)"
    animalsCountLabel.fontSize = 45
    animalsCountLabel.fontColor = SKColor.blackColor()
    animalsCountLabel.position = CGPoint (x: 630, y: 40)

    addChild(animalsCountLabel)
```

I need `animalsCount` to increase by 1 every time contact between 2 sprite nodes, `chicken1` and `savior`, is made. Here I have `animalsCount` increasing with collision detection:

```
 func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

        //Chicken1

        if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.Savior.rawValue && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.Chicken1.rawValue )  {

            println("chicken1 contact made")
            chicken1.hidden = true
            chicken1.setScale(0)

            animalsCount += 1
            animalsCountLabel.text = "\(animalsCount)"


        } else if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.Chicken1.rawValue && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.Savior.rawValue)  {

            println("chicken1 contact made")
            chicken1.hidden = true
            chicken1.setScale(0)

        }
```

(I only increase the score when `savior` collides with `chicken1` because it can't happen vice versa)
As it is, my label starts at 0 and `animalsCount` increase by 2 every time savior collides with chicken1.

I'm assuming this is because `animalsCount` goes up when savior begins contact with chicken1 AND when it ends contact.

How can I change this so `animalsCount` only goes up when contact begins? Or how else can I make `animalsCount` go up by 1 and not 2? 
I have already tried having `animalsCount` increment by 0.5 and got an error message.

Comment: is it not that this method is getting called twice because it's called for both bodies in a colliding pair?

Comment: This is not the case. `contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.Savior.rawValue` is the only line of code that is ever satisfied.